# JCrop - Can't move selection

Tags: jquery, move, selected, area

I have a simple `jcrop` example and I can't seem to figure out how to move the selection. I thought that it might be the JQuery library but I am using v1.3.2, which is what the demo uses. I have used `jcrop` in another site and everything works fine when I bring it up. I tried setting the `allowMove` option to `true` but it still doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="./jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./jquery.Jcrop.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            //alert('fda');
            //SET JCROP OPTIONS
            jcrop_api = $.Jcrop('#cropPhoto');
            jcrop_api.setOptions({ allowMove: true });
            jcrop_api.setOptions({ allowResize: false });
            jcrop_api.setSelect([0, 0, 200, 200]);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="cropPhoto" src="http://www.townattorneygeneral.com/images/CarlPerson019.jpg" alt="randomimage" style="border:1px solid #000000;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 24):

I know this is a kinda old, but unanswered so.

You have to include the css file that comes with the script it sets up the overlay and the gif.

Comment: Thanks a lot...I didn't have this exact but I've found error in my css file :)

Comment: Still today some can forget to add the css :D. Thank you.